# Laravel & Ardent - orderBy in $relationsData

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, ardent

In Eloquent, you can do this:

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('page');
}
```

And in Ardent, you can do this:

```
public static $relationsData = [
    'children' => [self::HAS_MANY, 'Page'],
];
```

---

In Eloquent, you can **also** do this:

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('page')->orderBy('sort_order', 'desc');
}
```

Is there any way to do that, or get the same effect as that in Ardent?

I really like the short Ardent notation, but don't want to have to call `$page->children->ordered()` with a scope just to order them, as they'll need to be ordered every single time it's called anyway.

Comment: Have you found a way?? I'm wondering the same

Comment: Nope, didn't find anything. Sorry

Comment: Any work around for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it's just not possible. You need the full definition if you want to do anything more than the basic relation functionality.